# Convert Array to Hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have this:

```
balance = ["Date", "2014-03-17", "The voice", 1, "Date", "2014-03-18", "Argo", 1, "Date", "2014-03-19", "The voice", 0]
```

When I use:

```
Hash[*balance]
```

It gives me:

```
{"Date"=>"2014-03-19", "The voice"=>0, "Argo"=>1}
```

Instead of:

```
   {"Date"=>"2014-03-17", "The voice"=>1, "Date"=>"2014-03-18", "Argo"=>1, "Date"=>"2014-03-19", "The voice"=>0}
```

Why? (Sorry if it is obvious.)

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @Darshan-JosiahBarber Don't try to fool people into think as if I made a mistake. The code **as of now** is reproducible precisely **because you changed it**.

Comment: @sawa The situation that was confusing to the OP and prompted the question was very much reproducible.  The detail that seems so important to you is, in my opinion, an inconsequential copy-paste error that changes nothing about the question.  I'm certainly not trying to "fool people" -- what an interesting suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the data structure you're asking for cannot exist as a Hash in Ruby, as it has duplicate keys.  One possibility that may work for you is to generate an Array of Hashes:

```
balance = ["Date", "2014-03-17", "The voice", 1,
           "Date", "2014-03-18", "Argo", 1,
           "Date", "2014-03-19", "The voice", 0]

balance.each_slice(4).collect {|h| Hash[*h]}
# => [{"Date"=>"2014-03-17", "The voice"=>1},
#     {"Date"=>"2014-03-18", "Argo"=>1},
#     {"Date"=>"2014-03-19", "The voice"=>0}]
```

Comment: Thanks, just what i wanted.can u explain please.

Comment: It grabs elements from `balance` in groups of four, does the Hash-splat thing you were already doing to each group, then collects the new Hashes back into an Array.

Answer (score 2):

According to [`Hash` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html):

> A Hash is a dictionary-like collection of **unique keys** and their
>   values.

There are multiple `Date`s, `The voice`s.

```
{'key' => 'value1', 'key' => 'value2'}
# => {"key"=>"value2"}
```

---

How about using an array of hashes?

```
[{'key' => 'value1'}, {'key' => 'value2'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because in your array `"The voice"` and `"Date"` occurred *multiple times*, and Hash hold latest updated value of any of its key. As per your array last entries `.."Date", "2014-03-19", "The voice", 0]`, causes your hash to hold latest values for the keys, `"date"` and `"The voice"`.

What you are looking for is not possible, but you can get as `[["Date", "2014-03-17"], ["The voice", 1],..]`

Answer (score 0):

```
Myarray=['a','b','c'] #Array initialize

hash={} #Hash initialize

#Access Array Element by index using each loop and put it in hash.

Myarray.each do |i|
 hash[Myarray.index(i)+1] = i.to_s
end

print hash 

Output:{1=>"a", 2=>"b", 3=>"c"}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.